Left Adjoint to a Forgetful Functor on $\mathsf{Grp}$
If $G$ is a group, then we can define an action of $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$ on the underlying set of $G$ as $a : \mathbb{Z} \times G \to G, a(n, g) = g^n$. This defines a functor $U$ from the category of groups to the category of $(\mathbb{Z}, \times)$-actions because group homomorphisms preserve this action. Does this functor have a left adjoint $F$, and if so, does it have a simple description? I'd also be interested in the case of abelian groups, which I don't expect to have a drastically different answer.
I think that $F$ would map any trivial action $a : \mathbb{Z} \times X \to X, a(n, x) = x$ to the trivial group, and it also seems that if $G$ is a cyclic group, then $F(U(G)) \cong G$. $U$ is not full so this does not hold of all groups however. Despite these specific cases, I'm still not sure what a general description would be.

So, to be clear, you're asking about the category of $M$-sets with $M$ being the multiplicative monoid of $\mathbb{Z}$, right?

If so, a theorem from George Bergman's category theory notes implies that it has a left adjoint if and only it's representable by a co-$M$-set object of $\mathsf{Grp}$, which I think would amount to a group $G$ with group homomorphisms $\varphi_n : G \to G$ for each $n$ satisfying $\varphi_m \circ \varphi_n = \varphi_{mn}$.  As far as I can tell, the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ with $\varphi_n$ being multiplication by $n$ should work as such a representing object.

Yes, that is the category I'm asking about

Yes, the functor has a left adjoint.  For each set $X$ with an action of the multiplicative monoid $\mathbb{Z}^\times$, we will define $F(X)$ via a presentation of the group.  This presentation will have generators $\{ e_x \mid x \in X \}$, and relations $e_x^n = e_{n \cdot x}$ for each $x\in X, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
To see this gives a left adjoint, note that by general results about group homomorphisms from a group with a given presentation, if $G$ is another group, then $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(F(X), G)$ is equivalent to the set maps $X \to G$ such that $f(x)^n = f(n\cdot x)$ for each $x\in X, n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  It is easy to see that this is in turn equivalent to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}^\times}(X, UG)$.  I will leave it as an exercise to show that with the induced functor structure on $F$, this equivalence is natural in both $X$ and $G$ (or to use any of the other characterizations of adjoint functors to complete the proof).
Note that in terms of units/counits, the unit of the adjunction would consist of the maps $X\to UFX$, $x \mapsto e_x$; and the counit of the adjunction would consist of the unique group homomorphisms $FUG \to G$ such that $e_g \mapsto g$ for $g \in G$.  The functor structure on $F$ would take a $\mathbb{Z}^\times$-equivariant map $f : X\to Y$ to the unique group homomorphism $FX \to FY$ such that $e_x \mapsto e_{f(x)}$ for each $x\in X$.

Notice that this approach works for literally every forgetful functor between categories of algebras for an algebraic theory.
